# Spring Data Mongodb Near Query not works

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I would like to find the nearest shop. So I wrote this code:

```
public class ShopRepositoryImpl extends GenericRepositoryImpl<ShopEntity, String> implements ShopRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    protected MongoTemplate template;

    @Override
    public GeoResult<ShopEntity> findNearest(Point location) {
        List<GeoResult<ShopEntity>> result = template.geoNear(
                NearQuery.near(location).maxDistance(new Distance(70, Metrics.KILOMETERS))
                        .query(new Query(Criteria.where("location")).limit(1)),
                ShopEntity.class).getContent();
        if (result.isEmpty())  {
            return null;
        } else {
            return result.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

In tomcat console there is :

```
2016-01-17 12:13:26.151  WARN 645 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]     o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Command execution of 
{ "geoNear" : "shop" , "query" : { "location" : { }} , "maxDistance" : 0.010974991600211786 , "distanceMultiplier" : 6378.137 , "num" : 1 , "near" : [ 48.8703939 , 2.0] , "spherical" : true} 
failed: no geo indices for geoNear
```

And I tried this :

```
public interface ShopRepository extends GenericRepository<ShopEntity, String>, ShopRepositoryCustom {
    GeoResults<ShopEntity> findByLocationNear(Point location, Distance distance);
}
```

No result

In my database I have one element :

```
  {
    "name": "A shop",
    "street": "149 Rue Montmartre",
    "city": "Paris",
    "zip": "75002",
    "country": "France",
    "location": {
      "x": 48.8703937,
      "y": 2.3422999
    }
  }
```

Comment: my Entity has :     @GeoSpatialIndexed
    private double[] location;

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the simple `@Query` annotation.
Index your location attribute by running in your mongod command line : `db.yourCollection.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )`.
Then use the query annotation in your MongoRepository :

```
    @Repository
public interface ShopRepository extends MongoRepository<Shop, String>{

    @Query(value = "{\"location\":\n" +
"       { $near :\n" +
"          {\n" +
"            $geometry : {\n" +
"               type : \"Point\" ,\n" +
"               coordinates : [ ?0, ?1] }\n" +
"          }\n" +
"       }}")
    public List<Shop> nearByShops(double longitude, double latitude);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with a near query recently, which I solved as follows:

```
mongoTemplate.indexOps(MyClass.class).ensureIndex(new GeospatialIndex("attribute.holding.coordinates"));
NearQuery nearQuery = NearQuery.near(x, y);
final GeoResults<MyClass> geoResults = mongoTemplate.geoNear(nearQuery, MyClass.class);
return geoResults.getContent().stream().map(GeoResult::getContent).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This explicitly applies a geospatial index, then uses it to lookup nearby objects.

Comment: It not works :( 2016-02-01 01:24:42.273  WARN 13601 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : Command execution of { "geoNear" : "shop" , "near" : [ 48.8865967 , 2.0] , "spherical" : false} failed: more than one 2d index, not sure which to run geoNear on

Comment: @Maryo your domain model is causing this query to not work...    mongoTemplate.indexOps(Device.class).ensureIndex(new GeospatialIndex("position"));  for example..'position' is the only property in domain i am querying on.

Answer (score 0):

To use near by first create an index `2dsphere` like this:

```
db.places.createIndex( { location: "2dsphere" } )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, read MongoDB docs
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/

You need:

1. Store the location data like this:

   location: {
   type: "Point",
   coordinates: [-73.846077, 40.828447]
   }
2. Create a geo index

   db.collection.createIndex( { location : "2dsphere" } )

You can make SpringData work for you, using this in your entity:

```
@GeoSpatialIndexed(type = GeoSpatialIndexType.GEO_2DSPHERE)
private MongodbLocation location;
```

And enabling index creation in the properties file:

```
data.mongodb.auto-index-creation: true
```

An example of POJO for the location object:

```
public class MongodbLocation {
    List<Double> coordinates;
    String type;
}
```

And don't forget: Point object and coordinates list need longitude first, then latitude.

Then... you can use something like this:

```
public interface AdRepository extends MongoRepository<AdEntity, String> {
    GeoResults<AdEntity> findByAddressLocationNear(Point p, Distance d);

    GeoPage<AdEntity> findByAddressLocationNear(Point p, Distance d, Pageable pageable);
}
```